# Minimize number of rectangles that cover all the points

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization

I have a 2d distribution of moving points with known trajectories represented in a 640x480 image. Here is the initial state:

[image: 2d points distribution]

I have to find the minimum number of rectangles with fixed dimensions (35x42 pixels) that are able to cover all my input data, minimizing also the overlapping areas for each step.

So far I tried to solve the problem using the hierarchical clustering algorithm cutting the dendogram when observations in each flat cluster have no greater a cophenetic distance than $t$. This approach works pretty well when points are quite scattered but, little by little they get closer and the solution gets worse because the number of overlapping rectangles increases:

[image: image with closer points].

I was thinking to use an optimization approach but I don't know how to model the system. Do you have some idea how to do this? Or, do you know other approaches to face this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: this looks like the 2D case of a more general problem, namely that of covering a set of $k$ points in $d$-space with fixed-sized hypersquares (or rectangles). the latter problem has been investigated in [this paper of Gonzalez from 1990](http://www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-1990/1990-32.pdf). there's an approximate algorithm given in there that runs in polynomial time.